# In Spring security how initialise User -(org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User)

Tags: java, spring

I just initialize User(org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) like this, in one service class, which implements UserDetailsService(org.springframework.security.core.userdetails),

`User user=new User(null, null, false, false, false, false, null);`

but it shows error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor**

then how can I initialize this User object?

**method**

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsernameAndUsertype(String username, String type) throws
        UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = new User(null, null, false, false, false, false, null);

    try {

        if (type.equals("normalUser")) {
            com.booktheservice.entity.NormalUser normalUser = normalUserService.readSpecific("name", username);

            boolean enabled = true;
            boolean accountNonExpired = true;
            boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
            boolean accountNonLocked = true;
            user = new User(
                    normalUser.getName(),
                    normalUser.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
                    enabled,
                    accountNonExpired,
                    credentialsNonExpired,
                    accountNonLocked,
                    getAuthorities("normalUser", false));


        }
        if (type.equals("adminUser")) {
            com.booktheservice.entity.AdminUser adminUser = adminUserService.readSpecific("name", username);

            boolean enabled = true;
            boolean accountNonExpired = true;
            boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
            boolean accountNonLocked = true;

            user = new User(
                    adminUser.getName(),
                    adminUser.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
                    enabled,
                    accountNonExpired,
                    credentialsNonExpired,
                    accountNonLocked,
                    getAuthorities("adminUser", false));

        }

        if (type.equals("serviceLister")) {
            com.booktheservice.entity.ServiceLister serviceLister = serviceListerService.readSpecific("name", username);

            boolean enabled = true;
            boolean accountNonExpired = true;
            boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
            boolean accountNonLocked = true;

            user = new User(
                    serviceLister.getName(),
                    serviceLister.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
                    enabled,
                    accountNonExpired,
                    credentialsNonExpired,
                    accountNonLocked,
                    getAuthorities("serviceLister", false));

        }
        return user;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by initialize User (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) like this:

User user=null;

Answer (score 0):

This is the constructor u are trying to call

```
public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        if (((username == null) || "".equals(username)) || (password == null)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor");
        }

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
        this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
        this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
        this.authorities = Collections.unmodifiableSet(sortAuthorities(authorities));
    }
```

You cannot pass null to some certain fields.

Comment: Yes I konw that. But I need to initialize that User object. Is there any other method to do that..?

Comment: then just give some dummy values for username and password, i did not get what u want to achieve.

Comment: I added my code in question. Can u please check that?

Comment: ur normalUser.getName() and/or adminUser.getName() and/or serviceLister.getName() is null or empty. Check them out and give some default values if empty or null. String normalUserUsername = StringUtils.empty(normalUser.getName()) ? "normal_user" : normalUser.getName();